# Difference in constraints iOS 7 and iOS 8. Xcode 6 seed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

So I have a UIViewController with a UIImageView and a Collection View, as well as a Navigation Bar. This app is only in portrait mode and won't change when rotating.

in iOS 7.1.2 and below, it shows up correctly, like this:
[image1 http://imageshack.com/a/img911/4185/koGDtt.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img911/4185/koGDtt.jpg)

In iOS 8, it shows up incorrectly where the collection view is at the very top of the screen behind the navigation bar, like this:
[image2 http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2531/NWYWsn.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/2531/NWYWsn.jpg)

I have been trying for a couple days now, varying ways of constraining the collection view and it has always yielded the same results. I have searched SO for an answer that may help me resolve this issue but have not been able to come up with something that worked.

I am generally constraining the top of the collection view to the superview (330), the leading and trailing edges to the edges of the superview (0), and then height/width constraints on the UICollectionView to it's dimensions (320, 80).

I tried making a new UIView in IB, constraining it to the outer edges of the superview, and then constraining the collectionView to this new UIView, but it still did the same thing. I'm at a loss here and really appreciate any help you all can give me.

Comment: Can you show the constraints that you have set up in IB please.

Comment: Yes @Fogmeister, here is a screen shot of the constraints:
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/6412/dMOhvP.png

Comment: I have absolutely no way of knowing whether you're dealing with the same problem, but I found that something in the way constraints are handled in UICollectionViewCells has changed with the XCode 6 upgrade. I have an app using UICollectionView that works fine when I compile & build it using XCode 5.1.1, but where the storyboard constraints don't work using XCode 6.0 (GM). All under iOS 7 BTW.

Comment: @ecotax that doesn't sounds like the same issue I'm having. Mine is different based on the iOS version, but I don't notice a difference across xCode versions. So compiling for iOS 7 from xCode 6 doesn't give me the same issue. Good luck, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out finally. It was completely unrelated to constraints and was in fact a line of code that displaced the entire UICollectionView in iOS 8.

In the -didSelectItemAtIndexPath method I made a call to update the selected indexPath of the collectionView using this line:

```
[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

I was also pre-selecting an cell at indexPath 0 in my -viewDidLoad so that the first item of the collection would be highlighted, which caused the -didSelectItemAtIndexPath to be called right away.

For some reason, the reloadItemsAtIndexPaths line would change the view of my entire collectionView to the top of the screen.

I replaced this line with:

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

and now everything works fine as intended.